# animate image from one side

Tags: android, animation, android-animation

I have an image which i have to animate from one side but the image is animating from both the side please help.[image]

I already tried this code but not working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false">
    <translate
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:fromYDelta="-90%"
        android:repeatCount="infinite"
        android:repeatMode="reverse"
        android:toXDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="90%" />
</set>
```

Code java

```
 Animation leftWing = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                R.anim.animation_wing_left);
        mainWingLeft5.startAnimation(leftWing);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rotate`

Try this:

```
<rotate
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromDegrees="-10"
    android:pivotX="100%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="500"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:repeatMode="reverse"
    android:toDegrees="10" />
```

Comment: hi @dr3K what if i want to do the reverse?